# Выведение построчного txt файла в консоль

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здраствуйте. Есть txt файл в котором каждая буква написана с новой строки. Как вывести информацию в одну строку?
Что есть в файле:
h
e
l
l
o
Что хочу получить:
hello

Comment: куда вывести: в файл, на консоль?

Comment: @slippyk да. Сейчас отредактирую заголовок

Comment: @slippyk а если в переменную?

Comment: Тоже не сложно, дополнил ответ, но смысла большие файлы читать в переменную не много

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, если не сохранять строку в переменную, а сразу выводить

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.rstrip(), end='')
```

С сохранением в переменную:

```
s = ''
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        s += line.rstrip()

print(s)
```

Или:

```
s = ''
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    s = ''.join([line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()])

print(s)
```